# Examples of Lie groups where $G\to G/H$ splits topologically but not as groups

Tags: lie-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $H$ a normal connected subgroup. I'm looking for examples where $G\to G/H$ has a section as topological spaces, but not as Lie groups.

My motivation here is to find a continuous analogue of extensions of discrete groups, where splittings always exist on the level of sets, but only exist as groups when the extension is a semidirect product.

I've looked at exact sequences of Lie groups, such as: $$1\to SU(n) \to U(n) \to U(1) \to 1$$

But in this case, the sequence is split so $U(n) \cong SU(n)\rtimes U(1)$. I've also looked at: $$1\to SU(2) \to SO(4) \to SO(3) \to 1$$

But I believe there is still a splitting here as well. (I couldn't find a reference but this seems to be the case)

(Side question: does a topological splitting imply that $G\to G/H$ is a trivial fibration, so that $G$ is homeomorphic to $H\times G/H$?)

Ideally, I'd like to see an example where $H$ is abelian. I'd also like to consider situations where $H$ isn't normal so $G/H$ is just a homogeneous space and not a group, but I'm not completely sure how to phrase the question in that case. Cohomological criteria are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: @DaveBenson Can't we just embed $U(1)$ in $U(n)$ as the group of diagonal matrices with $1$ in the last $n-1$ positions? Thanks for the comment on $SO(4)$, though I'm not sure how to use the fact that it's a central product to show that it's not a semidirect product.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think both sequences split. I'll delete my previous comments.

Comment: This might not be of interest to you since it's usually not normal, but if $H$ is maximal compact, then the coset space is Euclidean, and there is a section inducing a diffeomorphism between $H \times G/H$ and $G$.

Comment: For your second sequence, in general if $G/Z(G)$ acts on $G$ via the inner automorphisms then $G \rtimes G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to a central product $G \times_{Z(G)} G$, so the central product splits. I admit that I am surprised by this.

Comment: $G$ simply connected nilpotent not abelian, $H=[G,G]$: then $G\to G/[G,G]$ never splits (even as abstract groups). But topologically this splits (this is topologically conjugate, through exponentials, to a surjective linear map).

Comment: (For a very concrete example of @YCor's suggestion, let $G$ be the [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group), with abelianisation $\Big(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & a & c \\ 0 & 1 & b \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\Big) \mapsto (a,b)$.)

Comment: @Ycor Thanks, this is a great class of examples! And the Heisenberg group provides a nice example where the subgroup is abelian.

Comment: Is the $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ inside $\operatorname{SO}(4)$ by viewing the latter as $(\operatorname{SU}(2) \times \operatorname{SU}(2))/\langle(-1, -1)\rangle$ and inserting $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ on, say, the left?  Then you can take $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ to be the diagonally embedded $\operatorname{SU}(2)/\langle-1\rangle$.

Comment: For the side question, let $s\colon G/H\to G$ be a continuous (or smooth) section, then we have the isomorphism $G/H\times H \to G$ mapping $(x, h)\to s(x)\cdot h$.

Comment: @LSpice That looks right. Yes, I think these are the only two copies of SU(2) in SO(4).

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Ah yes, perfect, and works regardless of whether $H$ is normal.

Comment: Central extensions $A \to B \to C$ of topological groups are classified by the degree-two Segal-Mitchison group cohomology of $C$ with values in $A$. The ones that split topologically are classified by the degree-two continuous group cohomology of $C$ with values in $A$. In other words, every non-trivial continuous group 2-cocycle $c: C \times C \to A$ gives rise to a central extension that splits topologically, but not as groups.

Comment: By the way, if $A \to B \to C$ is a central extension of topological groups and $A$ is contractible, then it has a section. The Heisenberg  group mentioned above is an example of this situation, with $A=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @KonradWaldorf Continuous 2-cohomology is a simpler answer than I was expecting for central extensions. Should it be obvious that any continuous 2-cocycle gives rise to a topological splitting?

Comment: @AndrewDudzik: indeed. Given a continuous 2-cocycle, the central extension one constructs from it is (as a topological space) $A \times C$, and hence has the continuous section $c \mapsto (1,c)$. The cocycle only affects the group structure on $A \times C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A summary of some of the comments:

@YCor proposed a collection of examples given by $G\to [G, G]$ where $G$ is simply-connected nilpotent non-abelian.

Specifically, if $H$ is the Heisenberg group, we have an exact sequence that splits topologically but not as groups:

$$0\to \mathbb{R}\to H\to\mathbb{R}^2\to 0$$

@PiotrAchinger gave an answer to my parenthetical question: a continuous section $s$ does imply that the fibration is trivial, since we can identify $(x,h)$ with $s(x)\cdot h$.

Finally, @KonradWaldorf pointed out that the continuous group cohomology $H^2$ classifies extensions of the kind I'm interested in, at least in the central case, since a continuous 2-cocycle gives rise to a topological section.